# The underneath program presents no output plus no error

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, data-science, axes

```
from mpl_toolkits import mplot3d
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

y=[229500,273300,247000,195100,261000,179700,168500,234400,168800,180400,156200,288350,186750,202100,256800]
x = [1850,2190,2100,1930,2300,1710,1550,1920,1840,1720,1660,2405,1525,2030,2240]
z = [4,5,4,3,4,2,2,4,2,2,2,5,3,2,4]

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10,7))
ax = plt.axes(projection = "3d")

ax.scatter3D(x,y,z, color = "Green",marker = 'o');
ax.set_xlabel("House Price (INR)")
ax.set_ylabel("Area (Sq. ft)")
ax.set_zlabel("No. of Rooms")

plt.show()
```

The above program presents no output. I have been using Google Colab for this. Could someone point out the error or mistake that I am committing here? Your help would be appreciated by this newbie.
Thank You

Comment: I've just run this code in my CoLab, and it outputted. Could you share your CoLab or copy-paste this code to another sheet to check it out?

Comment: @AvivYaniv ThankYou. As you said, I tried the code in a new notebook and it worked. I don't know why it didn't work in the previous one. I guess I will learn all these minor nuances over time. Thank You again.